# JavaScript move node to position after lastChild

Tags: javascript

I've got an arrangement script that moves elements up or down visually (elements like `li` and `tr`) however when the element is already first I need to make it appear at the bottom instead. I've tried `appendChild` using the correct element references and get an error because the element I'm moving is already a child of it's parent. I have also tried using `insertBefore` without any luck

No frameworks.

So lets say we've got the parent element `s_parent`, we want to move the child element `s_move` and there are four child `tr` elements of `s_parent`, how do we move `s_move` *after* `s_parent.lastChild`?

```
var s_parent = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

var s_move = t.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
```

Comment: please put ur html on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Node.appendChild** method on parent node:

`s_parent.appendChild(s_move);`

which will add your element after last child of the parent node.

**Good to know:**

When manipulating DOM elements with vanilla JS, be aware of possible text nodes produced by templating system or by hand indentation in your HTML markup.

Compressed markup:
`<ul><li></li><li></li></ul>`

- `ul.firstChild` is first `li`
- first `li.nextSibling` is second `li`

but indented markup: `<ul> <li> </li> <li> </li> </ul>`

- `ul.firstChild` is `#textNode`
- first `li.nextSibling` is `#textNode`

Check:

- [Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)
- [Working example with compressed HTML @JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kabuxusofi/6/edit)

Comment: Thanks, I was working on creating and working out a standalone test case, discovered this and then came and saw that you recommended the `#text` nodes. By using two `for` loops and defining the `tag` name of the child element I was then able to utilize `getElementsByTagName(tag)` in the second `for` loop and make the code work both with elements containing `#text` nodes and those without any.

Answer (score 1):

You need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild

In your case:

```
s_parent.appendChild(s_move);
```

From docs:

> The Node.appendChild() method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. **If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position.**